# BeautyTips + Jquery Update not working

Tags: 7, ajax

Is it possible to get [BeautyTips](https://drupal.org/project/beautytips) working with a new version of jquery 1.7 or 1.8.

Firebug returns the error.

```
`Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new p.fn.init(a,b,c)} has no method 'curCSS'` - jquery.bt.min.js?v=0.9.5-rc1:97
```

Is there a new version of jquery.bt.min.js that will work?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in a contributed module, and should be reported to the module's issue queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the jQuery blog](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/), the function curCSS was deprecated in jQuery 1.8:

> $.curCSS: This method was simply an alias for jQuery.css() from jQuery
>   1.3 onward. Although it has never been part of the documented API, some external code has been known to use it, perhaps thinking it was
>   “more efficient.” Now it’s “more gone.”

but since its simply an alias its possible to patch the beauty tips plugin to fix this. There is a patch here on Drupal.org that [does just this](https://drupal.org/node/1902324) and its been committed to the dev release. Its not ideal as you have to patch the library to get this to work but its really your only strategy since the beautytips plugin hasn't been upgraded for the newer versions of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. Applying the patch manually worked. The dev gave the same issue for me.